# iOS10, production build, crashed on launch

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, testflight, launch

i never encounter this issue before.
my problem is that the build i uploaded to testflight (using appstore provisioning) always crashed on launch. 
No crash report.

but if i distribute the build via crashlytics using adhoc / development provisioning, it worked fine.

this is only happened with ios 10 devices.

anyone have an idea why is this happening ?

i'm using XCode 8.

thank you.

Comment: are you using camera or calendar or  location manger ?

Comment: i'm using bluetooth, location manager, and photos.

Comment: i already added these keys to my plist file : NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription